# Output numbers from a file in a different order

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I have a file that contains:

```
1 2 3 4
1 3 5 4 8
3 2 1
```

Each line has a different number of digits. And there are 1000 more like this.

I want the output like this:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 0
1 3
3 5
5 4
4 8
8 0
3 2
2 1
1 0
```

### edit made to this post!!

#### i mean if this is last digit in line put that digit and then zero besides it.

#### for example if digit is last in that line we put in output new line that digit and zero

```
4 0 and others:see output sample tnx
```

in above example and

How can I do that, in `perl` `awk` or `bash`

i use this but its not working :((

```
awk '{
for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
{
if ( $(i+1) == "")
print $i, "0"
else
print $i, $(i+1)
}
}' UniqASinline> inTestAst
```

the outpute file of Mr.glenn jackman way:

for this imput:

```
3549 
3549 10026 
3549 10026 10010 
3549 10026  
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d %d\n", $i, $(i+1))}' filename

3549 
3549 10026
10026 
3549 10026
10026 10010
10010 
3549 10026
10026
```

but we expect:

```
3549 0
3549 10026
10026 0
3549 10026
10026 10010
10010 0
3549 10026
10026 0
```

tnx

Comment: Sounds like a homework =)

Comment: i can do it by sending item into array and then process the array but if we have 1000 lines its too slow in bash :(( !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i, $(i+1)}' filename
```

EDIT: to reflect your new requirement

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d %d\n", $i, $(i+1))}' filename
# ----------------^
```

This takes advantage of the fact that awk treats uninitialized values (here `$(NF+1)`) as an empty string (in string context) or zero (in numeric context).

Comment: oh i'm sorry ive change the out put i need  this , in above post edited

Comment: i mean if this is last digit in line put that digit and then zero besides it.

Comment: how could i chane this awk?? tnx alot

Comment: i want too put 0 not free space

Comment: tnx but your script is doing 1 2,2 3,3 4,4""(free space not "0")

Comment: hmm, not for me, it prints a zero. Show exactly what you're doing

Comment: its print nothing in mine :((

Comment: i edit my post to show you the results\

Comment: What does `awk --version` show you?

Comment: on ubuntu 12.10 returns awk: not an option: --version

Comment: How about `type -a awk`?

Comment: awk is /usr/bin/awk is the response

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
 perl -lane '$c=0; for (@F){ print "$F[$c]\t$F[$c+=1]" if $F[$c+1]}' file.txt
```

Or decomposed :

```
perl -lane '
    $c=0;
    for (@F) {
        print "$F[$c]\t$F[$c+=1]"
            if $F[$c+1];
    }
' file.txt
```

## EXPLANATIONS

- `lane` switchs means : l=newlines ; a=autosplit in @F array ; n=like `while (<>)` magic diamond operator ; e=basic switch to run a command
- `$c=0` assign 0 to a counter
- `for (@F) {` for each element of the current line
- `print "$F[$c]\t$F[$c+=1]"` : print array element with indice $c + tab + $c+1
- `if $F[$c+1];` : apply last line only if $F[$c+1] is not null

Or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (same algorithm), maybe more human readable for beginners :

```
while read a; do
    arr=( $a )
    for ((i=0; i< ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
        [[ ${arr[i+1]} ]] && echo "${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]}"
    done
done < file.txt
```

Comment: While this (probably, can't test) gives the OP what they want, it would be nice to explain what exactly it does, so that everyone seeing it can learn a little.

Comment: Sure, I do it now

Comment: i'v got the error :((  unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Comment: Sorry, a quote forgotten =)

Comment: its take too long!!!how we can optimized it?

Comment: Be precise. Have you tested the 3 different versions ?

Comment: Can you show us a little bit of search effort ? Google have tons of results for this kind of things :/ If it's really a homework, in 1 week you will forget all this stuff... Sniff.

Comment: oh i'm sorry!! tnx. i got it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure bash solution:

```
while read -a a; do
    for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]}-1;++i)); do
        echo "${a[@]:i:2}"
    done
done < file.txt
```